# CCA: Chrome identity pops up Account Chooser every time

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-api, google-chrome-app

I am making a Chrome/Android/iOS app using the `cca` toolchain.  I am using the `chrome.identity` API to get an `access_token` to interact with Google APIs.

When I set `interactive` to `false` (`immediate` to `true`) the app is able to get the token without showing the permissions dialog again, but it still shows the account chooser every time on my Android device.  This ruins the app experience because every time it is opened the user gets an annoying dialog.  How can I make the app remember the chosen account after the first time, like it does with the permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android, you can specify `accountHint` in the `details` argument of calls to `getAuthToken`.  For example:

```
var details = { interactive: true, accountHint: 'email@address.com' };
var callback = function(token, account) { ... };
chrome.identity.getAuthToken(details, callback);
```

This will bypass the account chooser dialog.  Note that the callback has `account`, which can be stored for this purpose.

Unfortunately, this is Android-only; Chrome on desktop doesn't like it when you add extra stuff to `details`.  You'll need to use [`chrome.runtime.getPlatformInfo`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getPlatformInfo) to determine what platform you're running on, so that you can create and pass the right `details` object.  On Android, `platformInfo.os` will be `cordova-android`.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, and it works!  Good call on cordova-android, docs say it will be only android.